# Oracle Entity Framework Connection String

Tags: database, oracle, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net core oracle entity framework. I am writing default connection to `appsettings.json`

But I got

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-00942: The table
> or schema doesnt exist.

I think I make mistake at connection string but I dont know where

my database name `TEST` my schema name `DBTEST`( all my db table inside this i must to connect to dbtest for insert ,select or  update ) but I couldn't so that I got table or view doesn't exist.

```
 "DefaultConnection": "Data
 Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= ip
 )(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test)(SERVER=TEST)));User
 Id=UserName;Password=*******;"
```

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-00942: The table or schema doesnt exist.

This means that connection was successful, but you got error during parsing your query. You need to check your query.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear, either the table is not there or your user ( the one you connect with ) has no privileges to see the table.

You need to run:

```
SQL> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME TO USER ;
```

Replace schema.table_name for your schema and table, and user for TEST, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use special attributes for the class that represents the table in your DbContext to determine which DB table you are refering to. Use upper case to match the Oracle table.

```
    [Table(name:"BANK_ORDERS", Schema ="STAGING")]
    public class Orders
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
```

Example for table STAGING.BANK_ORDERS